# Función retorna Anyval

Tags: scala

En **Scala**, ¿por qué una expresión de este tipo devuelve AnyVal? (Esperaba un boleano)

```
if (expr0)
    if ((expr1)&&(expr2))
        true
    else if (expr3)
        false
    else
        recFun(arg0, arg1)
```

Nota 1: recFun es una función recursiva...

Nota 2: Es la última línea de la propia función recursiva...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás usando una expresión `if` sin parte `else`, algo que equivale a:

```
if (expr0)
    res_booleano // resultado del if anidado
else
   ()
```

O sea, que cuando `expr0 == false`, el resultado del `if` es `()`, de tipo `Unit`. En total, todo el `if` acaba teniendo el tipo `AnyVal`, al ser el *supertipo* común de `Boolean` y `Unit`.

Comment: ¿De qué otra forma, siguiendo la lógica de la función, se podría expresar?

Comment: ¿Qué debería retornar si `expr0 == false`? Pues añade un `else` con ese valor.

Comment: Quería que expr3 sé evaluara sí expr0 es cierta, era para no hacer dos evaluaciones de expr0, una en cada uno del segundo y tercer if. No había pensado que esto pasaba y no hay un caso de expr0 siendo falso... Muchas gracias!

Comment: Desconociendo el contexto completo, siempre se puede refactorizar y dejarlo mejor:

```
if (expr0)
  ((expr1&&expr2) || !expr3)
else
  recFun(arg0, arg1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Si el rendimiento no es un problema mayor lo mejor que puedes utilizar para el problema que tienes es un pattern matching, te ofrece un código mucho más limpio.

```
user.password == enteredPassword match {
   case true => println("User is authenticated")
   case false => println("Entered password is invalid")
}
```

Comment: Esto no contesta la pregunta.